# How to convert grades into points using pandas?

Tags: pandas

My code returns an error when I run it. Why might this be so?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

points = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
bins = ['X','E','D-','D','D+','C-','C','C+','B-','B','B+','A-','A']
df1['DA'] = pd.cut(df1.AA,bins,labels=points)
df1['DE'] = pd.cut(df1['BB'],bins,labels=points)
df1['CDI'] = pd.cut(df1.CC,bins,labels=points)
```

The error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'X'
```

EDITS
Those are student grades that I want to convert to points. Like grade A is 12 points in that order...

Comment: `bins` must be numeric bin boundaries. What are you trying to do? (And what is the point of `import csv`?)

Comment: Since we can't sample `sample.csv` we can't tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @cs95, sample.csv contains student grades, no names, just the grades only.

Comment: Oh, I see. You've accidentally interchanged the points and bins arguments. I think that should fix it.

Comment: It's not accidental. What I have iny csv are the grades to be changed to points. I think that should be the arrangement? Unless such an operation is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) instead. First create a dict with the conversion you want to apply, then you can create your columns

```py
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'AA': ['X','E','D-','D','D+','C-','C','C+','B-','B','B+','A-','A']})

# conversion dict
points = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
grades = ['X','E','D-','D','D+','C-','C','C+','B-','B','B+','A-','A']
conversion = dict(zip(grades, points))

# applying conversion
df['DA'] = df.AA.replace(conversion)
```

The DataFrame will now look like:

```py
    AA  DA
0   X   0
1   E   1
2   D-  2
3   D   3
4   D+  4
5   C-  5
6   C   6
7   C+  7
8   B-  8
9   B   9
10  B+  10
11  A-  11
12  A   12
```